# Angular 4 - sharing components from my project

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I have an Angular project in which I've developed many UI components that I'd like to use in different Angular projects and share them in the npm community.

All of those components are gathered in a shared module that I've made.

What would be the best and easiest way to compile that module for publishing on npm for example?

Example file tree:

```
myAngularProject/
├──package.json
├──src/
   └──app/
      └──app.module.ts
      └──app.component.ts
      └──app.routing.ts
      └──...
      └──myComponentLibrary/
         └──myComponentLibrary.module.ts // <- this
         └──datepicker
         └──button
         └──...
```

Answer (score 3):

In Angular terms, this is called a "library" ... so that is the best term to use to find more information.

Here is a link to an article that may help: https://medium.com/@ngl817/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

Comment: I would like to use webpack for this task and not ng-packagr.
Mainly because this is a big project, and we can't depend on small projects that are very likely to remain unmaintained